# HTTPS Image URL Stopped Working in VS 2017 Project

Tags: c#, wpf, url, https, imagesource

I have a VS 2017 WPF project deployed to a number of clients (desktop app). The app displays images of staff members. The image is set using a URL as follows:

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(gFunc.myStaff[ix_staff].PicURL, UriKind.Absolute));
brdPicture.Background = ib;
```

PicURL is in the format: https://mySite/StaffPics/123.jpg

Suddenly, a few days ago, the images stopped working. When I run the app in debug I can see that the ImageSource has an error as follows:

```
Metadata = '((System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)ib.ImageSource).Metadata' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

Strangely, if I change the code and hard code the URL making it HTTP instead of HTTPS, the images are displayed. Yet if I open the URL in a browser using either HTTP or HTTPS, the picture displays no problem.

Has anyone experienced this before or know why this is happening? I've tried searching online but I can't find anything specific.

Comment: Ask if the server disabled  old versions of TLS and enforced TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.

Comment: I agree with Oguz, TLS version may be the issue. Which TLS versions are supported depends on the used Windows version. Hence I would assume that you are using an outdated Windows version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i'll contact the hosting company and check the TLS versions they are supporting.